# CakePhp2 autocomplete (jquery-ui folding) not working without ajax, only with array of available inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, cakephp-2.0

I am using **cakephp2**.

I want to make **autocomplete in cakephp2**, but not with ajax, it is array where are autocomplete`s available inputs. I have simple LocationsController (not important but i enclosed it) where i have:

```
class LocationsController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'Locations';

    public function index() {                
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Example - title');                 
    }
}
```

I have a view/locations/**index.ctp** where i Have

```
<div id="big_input_normal" >                                
<form>
   <input type="text" id="the_big_one" class="big_input_selection" />
   </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var names = [ "Bratislava", "Praque", "Trstena" ];

        var accentMap = {
            "á": "a",
            "ö": "o",
            "é": "e"
        };
        var normalize = function( term ) {
            var ret = "";
            for ( var i = 0; i < term.length; i++ ) {
                ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
            }
            return ret;
        };

        $( "#the_big_one" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
                    value = value.label || value.value || value;
                    return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
                }) );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Ofcourse i have included in head :

```
<script src="./app/webroot/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="./app/webroot/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="./app/webroot/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="./app/webroot/js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="./app/webroot/js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

**To sum up:**
I am using CAKEPHP2 (it is version 2 NOT 1.3), I want to make autocomplete with jquery, i downloaded jquery-ui and i have followed the examples folding http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ 
I have made it, have a look at example codes, but there is a problem, it DOES NOT WORK.

Javascripts are after the page to client is rendered defaultly blocked ? 
Or where is the problem? Please help me, am losing my mind with this primitive problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of the javascript inclusions are incorrect. They should reference the js file like so:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```

To get cake to do this automatically, you can do:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.7.1.js'); ?>
```